# Scrapy - Extract items from table

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Trying to get my head around Scrapy but hitting a few dead ends.

I have a 2 Tables on a page and would like to extract the data from each one then move along to the next page.

Tables look like this (First one is called Y1, 2nd is Y2) and structures are the same.

```
<div id="Y1" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 15px;">
                                <h2>First information</h2><hr style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px;">                    

                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-curved">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="tCol1" style="padding: 10px;">First Col Head</th>
                            <th class="tCol2" style="padding: 10px;">Second Col Head</th>
                            <th class="tCol3" style="padding: 10px;">Third Col Head</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Info 1</td>
                            <td>Monday 5 September, 2016</td>
                            <td>Friday 21 October, 2016</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="vevent">
                            <td class="summary"><b>Info 2</b></td>
                            <td class="dtstart" timestamp="1477094400"><b></b></td>
                            <td class="dtend" timestamp="1477785600">
                            <b>Sunday 30 October, 2016</b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Info 3</td>
                            <td>Monday 31 October, 2016</td>
                            <td>Tuesday 20 December, 2016</td>
                        </tr>


                    <tr class="vevent">
                        <td class="summary"><b>Info 4</b></td>                      
                        <td class="dtstart" timestamp="1482278400"><b>Wednesday 21 December, 2016</b></td>
                        <td class="dtend" timestamp="1483315200">
                        <b>Monday 2 January, 2017</b></td>
                    </tr>



                </tbody>
            </table>
```

As you can see, the structure is a little inconsistent but as long as I can get each td and output to csv then I'll be a happy guy.

I tried using xPath but this only confused me more.

My last attempt:

```
import scrapy

class myScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "myScraper"

allowed_domains = ["mysite.co.uk"]
start_urls =    (
                'https://mysite.co.uk/page1/',
                )

def parse_products(self, response):
    products = response.xpath('//*[@id="Y1"]/table')
    # ignore the table header row
    for product in products[1:]  
       item = Schooldates1Item()
       item['hol'] = product.xpath('//*[@id="Y1"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]').extract()[0]
       item['first'] = product.xpath('//*[@id="Y1"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').extract()[0]
       item['last'] = product.xpath('//*[@id="Y1"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]').extract()[0]
       yield item
```

No errors here but it just fires back lots of information about the crawl but no actual results.

Update:

```
  import scrapy

       class SchoolSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "school"

allowed_domains = ["termdates.co.uk"]
start_urls =    (
                'https://termdates.co.uk/school-holidays-16-19-abingdon/',
                )

  def parse_products(self, response):
  products = sel.xpath('//*[@id="Year1"]/table//tr')
 for p in products[1:]:
  item = dict()
  item['hol'] = p.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
  item['first'] = p.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
  item['last'] = p.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
  yield item
```

This give me: **IndentationError: unexpected indent**

if I run the amended script below (thanks to @Granitosaurus) to output to CSV (-o schoolDates.csv) I get an empty file:

```
import scrapy

class SchoolSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "school"
allowed_domains = ["termdates.co.uk"]
start_urls = ('https://termdates.co.uk/school-holidays-16-19-abingdon/',)

def parse_products(self, response):
    products = sel.xpath('//*[@id="Year1"]/table//tr')
    for p in products[1:]:
        item = dict()
        item['hol'] = p.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
        item['first'] = p.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
        item['last'] = p.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
        yield item
```

This is the log:

- 2017-03-23 12:04:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
  2017-03-23 12:04:08 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0
  pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2017-03-23
  12:04:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening
  on ... 2017-03-23 12:04:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200)
  https://termdates.co.uk/robots.txt> (referer: None) 2017-03-23
  12:04:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://termdates.co.uk/school-holidays-16-19-abingdon/> (referer:
  None) 2017-03-23 12:04:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] **ERROR: Spider error
  processing https://termdates.co.uk/school-holidays-16-19-abingdon/> (referer:
  None)** Traceback (most recent call last): File
  "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653,
  in _ runCallbacks
     current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)   File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.3-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spiders__init__.py",
  line 76, in parse
     raise NotImplementedError NotImplementedError 2017-03-23 12:04:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished) 2017-03-23
  12:04:08 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
  {'downloader/request_bytes': 467,  'downloader/request_count': 2, 
  'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2, 
  'downloader/response_bytes': 11311,  'downloader/response_count': 2, 
  'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,  'finish_reason':
  'finished',  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 23, 12, 4, 8,
  845000),  'log_count/DEBUG': 3,  'log_count/ERROR': 1, 
  'log_count/INFO': 7,  'response_received_count': 2, 
  'scheduler/dequeued': 1,  'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1, 
  'scheduler/enqueued': 1,  'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1, 
  'spider_exceptions/NotImplementedError': 1,  'start_time':
  datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 23, 12, 4, 8, 356000)} 2017-03-23 12:04:08
  [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

**Update 2**: (Skips row)
This pushes result to csv file but skips every other row.

The Shell shows
    **{'hol': None, 'last': u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', 'first': None}**

```
import scrapy

class SchoolSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "school"
allowed_domains = ["termdates.co.uk"]
start_urls = ('https://termdates.co.uk/school-holidays-16-19-abingdon/',)

def parse(self, response):
    products = response.xpath('//*[@id="Year1"]/table//tr')
    for p in products[1:]:
        item = dict()
        item['hol'] = p.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
        item['first'] = p.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract_first()
        item['last'] = p.xpath('td[3]/text()').extract_first()
        yield item
```

**Solution**: Thanks to @**vold**
This crawls all pages in start_urls and deals with the inconsistent table layout

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from SchoolDates_1.items import Schooldates1Item

class SchoolSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "school"
allowed_domains = ["termdates.co.uk"]
start_urls = ('https://termdates.co.uk/school-holidays-16-19-abingdon/',
              'https://termdates.co.uk/school-holidays-3-dimensions',)

def parse(self, response):
    products = response.xpath('//*[@id="Year1"]/table//tr')
    # ignore the table header row
    for product in products[1:]:
        item = Schooldates1Item()
        item['hol'] = product.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract_first()
        item['first'] = product.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract_first()
        item['last'] = ''.join(product.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract()).strip()
        item['url'] = response.url
        yield item
```

Comment: Please provide more information: What did you try? What code? Which XPATH expression confuses you? Did you read the Scrapy Tutorial about [Selectors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)?

Comment: Hi rfelten, I have added my latest code above. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site you want to parse? Also, try not using `tbody` in xpath expression.

Comment: @vold any reason not to use tbody? seems like an obvious way to avoid parsing header rows.

Comment: @stutray tbody is added by browsers like Mozilla and Chrome, and it does not exists in original HTML source-code.

Comment: `This give me: IndentationError: unexpected indent` your code is not indented correctly. This is the correct indentation: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8982858

Comment: Thanks folks. Please see edit for further issues

Comment: @stutray did you use scrapy [shell](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) for debugging and checking if scrapy return something? 
If not, give a try, it's a perfect tool for debug.

Comment: Try to rename `parse_products` to `parse`. See this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600064/scrapy-request-return-notimplementederror

Comment: I changed `parse_products` to`parse`. An error shows as: **NameError: global name 'sel' is not defined** - FIXED - Changed 'sel.xpath' to 'response.xpath'

Comment: See **Update 2**. It seems to be skipping rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138839/discussion-between-vold-and-stutray).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to slightly correct your code. Since you already select all elements within the table you don't need to point again to a table. Thus you can shorten your xpath to something like this`td[1]//text()`.

```
def parse_products(self, response):
    products = response.xpath('//*[@id="Year1"]/table//tr')
    # ignore the table header row
    for product in products[1:]  
       item = Schooldates1Item()
       item['hol'] = product.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract_first()
       item['first'] = product.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract_first()
       item['last'] = product.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract_first()
       yield item
```

Edited my answer since @stutray provide the link to a site.

Comment: `./` is not neccessary here, since expression is already bound to first level. If you'd look for any descendant you would need to use `.//` indeed. Also `extract_first()` is a relatively new shortcut to `extract()[0]` :)

Comment: I agree and correct my answer, but without link to a site, it's all I can suggest :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use CSS Selectors instead of xPaths, I always find CSS Selectors easy.

```
def parse_products(self, response):

    for table in response.css("#Y1 table")[1:]:
       item = Schooldates1Item()
       item['hol'] = product.css('td:nth-child(1)::text').extract_first()
       item['first'] = product.css('td:nth-child(2)::text').extract_first()
       item['last'] = product.css('td:nth-child(3)::text').extract_first()
       yield item
```

Also do not use `tbody` tag in selectors. [Source:](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/firefox.html)

> Firefox, in particular, is known for adding  elements to tables. Scrapy, on the other hand, does not modify the original page HTML, so you won’t be able to extract any data if you use  in your XPath expressions.

Comment: There's no difference whether you use css or xpath, in this case xpath is even more straight forward, e.g. `td[1]`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with these xpaths for the html source you've provided:

```
products = sel.xpath('//*[@id="Y1"]/table//tr')
for p in products[1:]:
    item = dict()
    item['hol'] = p.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
    item['first'] = p.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
    item['last'] = p.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
    yield item
```

Above assumes that each table row contains 1 item.

Comment: TBODY is added by browser like Mozilla and Chrome and it doesnt exists in source-code of HTML response, so your xpath wont work.

Comment: @Umair well in the context of OP's code it would work :P. Also you imply that OP doesn't use a browser or some rendering to download the source. So in the context of this question my original answer would work, but adjusted the answet nevertheless to reflect your point.

Comment: Thanks for all your input folks. Please see my edit with the site i'm trying to scrape

Comment: quick question - why is it `td[1]` for each of the xpaths - are the `td` s being removed by `.extract_first()`