# how to store a table with scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new in Scrapy and I have some troubles to get a table data.
I'm trying to store in a file the table with id = grdTableView_DXMainTable from:
view-source:http://databank.worldbank.org/data/reports.aspx?source=2&series=SE.PRM.NENR&country=

I'm using the following code:

```
import scrapy

class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "education"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
          'http://databank.worldbank.org/data/reports.aspx?source=2&series=SE.PRM.NENR&country=',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'education-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:    
            f.write(hxs.select('//table[@class="grdTableView_DXMainTable"]/td.//text()').extract())      
            self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

The resulting html file is empty. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy - Extract items from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947417/scrapy-extract-items-from-table)

Answer (score 1):

There are some points on your code that aren't correct:

1) You are using `hxs.select` which hasn't be defined in any part of your code.

2) The value `grdTableView_DXMainTable` is not the `class` name, is the `ID`. You can extract all the table info by using: 
  `response.xpath('//table[@id="grdTableView_DXMainTable"]//td//text()').extract()`

3) If you want to keep all the HTML code it would be better to do this instead:
    `response.xpath('//table[@id="grdTableView_DXMainTable"]').extract_first()`

Comment: I tried with your code but if I try to save the data in a file it does not storage anything.

Comment: Have you tried using the scrapy shell and debug each step and see where it fails? I used that and it worked great to me.