# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Using Python 3,Scrapy 1.7.3 to 
Following using following link [Scrapy - Extract items from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947417/scrapy-extract-items-from-table)

but it is giving me error of AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'xpath'

```
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" class="GridViewStyle" id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview" rules="all" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody><tr class="GridViewHeaderStyle" style="background-color:#66B6F4;">
<th scope="col">
<span id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview_ctl01_SUBHEADING_CODES_HEADING" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px;">HS-Code</span>
</th><th scope="col">
<span id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview_ctl01_SUBHEADING_DESCRIPTION_HEADING" style="padding:20px 20px 20px 5px;font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px;margin:2px">Item Description</span>
</th>
</tr><tr class="GridViewRowStyle">
<td style="width:15%;">
<a href="http://link.domain" id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview_ctl02_SUBHEADING_CODES" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px;">value1</a>
</td><td style="width:85%;">
<a href="http://link.domain" id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview_ctl02_SUBHEADING_DESCRIPTION" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px;">value1</a>
</td>
</tr><tr class="GridViewAlternatingRowStyle">
<td>
<a href="http://link.domain" id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview_ctl03_SUBHEADING_CODES" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px;">value1</a>
</td><td>
<a href="http://link.domain" id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview_ctl03_SUBHEADING_DESCRIPTION" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px;">value1</a>
</td>
</tr><tr class="GridViewRowStyle">
<td>
<a href="http://link.domain" id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview_ctl04_SUBHEADING_CODES" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px;">value1</a>
</td><td>
<a href="http://link.domain" id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview_ctl04_SUBHEADING_DESCRIPTION" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px;">value1</a>
</td>
</tr><tr class="GridViewAlternatingRowStyle">
<td>
<a href="http://link.domain" id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview_ctl05_SUBHEADING_CODES" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px;">value1</a>
</td><td>
<a href="http://link.domain" id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview_ctl05_SUBHEADING_DESCRIPTION" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px;">value1</a>
</td>
</tr><tr class="GridViewRowStyle">
<td>
<a href="http://link.domain" id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview_ctl06_SUBHEADING_CODES" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px;">value1</a>
</td><td>
<a href="http://link.domain" id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview_ctl06_SUBHEADING_DESCRIPTION" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px;">value1</a>
</td>
</tr><tr class="GridViewAlternatingRowStyle">
<td>
<a href="http://link.domain" id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview_ctl07_SUBHEADING_CODES" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px;">value1</a>
</td><td>
<a href="http://link.domain" id="ctl00_BodyContents_subheading_gridview_ctl07_SUBHEADING_DESCRIPTION" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;font-size: 14px;">value1</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Scrapy code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
class CybexbotSpider(scrapy.Spider): 
   name = 'cybexbot'
   allowed_domains = ['http://links.com']
   start_urls = ['http://links.com']
   def parse(self, response):
       data=response.xpath('//tr[contains(@class,"GridView")]').extract()
       for d in data[1:]:
         print(type(d))
         temp=dict()
         temp['Code']=d.xpath('tr//td[1]/a/text()').extract()
         temp['Desc']=d.xpath('tr//td[2]/a/text()').extract()
         yield temp
```

created temp dict and yield its value

error i am getting is

```
  temp['Code']=d.xpath('tr//td[1]/a/text()').extract()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import scrapy
class CybexbotSpider(scrapy.Spider): 
   name = 'cybexbot'
   allowed_domains = ['http://links.com']
   start_urls = ['http://links.com']
   def parse(self, response):
       data=response.xpath('//tr[contains(@class,"GridView")]')
       for d in data[1:]:
         print(type(d))
         temp=dict()
         temp['Code']=d.xpath('tr//td[1]/a/text()').extract()
         temp['Desc']=d.xpath('tr//td[2]/a/text()').extract()
         yield temp
```

Once you extract it, it becomes a string so the library can no longer process it

Comment: How do you make the str queryset, stop beeing a string?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like this (notice how I use **relative** XPath to get values):

```
   for row in response.xpath('//tr[contains(@class,"GridView")][position() > 1]'):
     temp=dict()
     temp['Code'] = row.xpath('.//td[1]/a/text()').extract_first() # may be you need .extract() here
     temp['Desc'] = row.xpath('.//td[2]/a/text()').extract_first() # may be you need .extract() here
     yield temp
```